# How to calculate how many items goes in which group?

Tags: javascript

Given a number of groups (g) and a number of records (r) how to calculate how many records goes in each group by evenly distributing them?

Result should be the same as the following function, but how to get the same result without creating each array?

```
func = ( g, r ) => {
    groups = [...Array(g).keys()].map( () => [] );
    for(i=0, j=0; i<r;i++) {
        groups[j].push(i);
        j++;
        if ( j === groups.length) j = 0; 
    }

    return groups.map( (v) => v.length );
}
func(4, 2); //[1, 1, 0, 0]
func(4, 10); //[3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
func = ( g, r ) => {
  const groups = Array(g).fill(Math.floor(r / g));
  for (let i = 0; i < (r % g); i += 1) {
    groups[i] += 1;
  }

  return groups;
}
```

That starts by setting each group to the number of items that can be evenly distributed between them. And then the remainder is used to add in the remaining elements.